# Passing DbContext through dependency injection to BackgroundService throwing exception

Tags: dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, backgroundworker, .net-core-3.1

I'm trying to pass EF Core `Dbcontext` to my `BackgroundService` through dependency injection but somehow cannot get the hang of it.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to do it right/better/easier/another way (not cumbersome if possible)?

I'm using `services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>` to add the DbContext in `HostBuilder`, then trying to receive it in the constructor of my `BackgroundService`.

I added the `DbContext` constructor receiving the `DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options` and passing it to the base constructor of `DbContext` in my context, which is the way described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation)

Here's the exception I keep getting when starting the application:

```
System.AggregateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: XXXX.SenderService': Cannot consume scoped service 'XXXX.Entities.MyDbContext' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService'.)
  Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DefaultServiceProviderFactory.CreateServiceProvider(IServiceCollection containerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ServiceFactoryAdapter`1.CreateServiceProvider(Object containerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at XXXX.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\WORK\REPOS\CRR\Main\XXXX\Program.cs:line 16

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: XXXX.SenderService': Cannot consume scoped service 'XXXX.Entities.MyDbContext' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService'.

Inner Exception 2:
InvalidOperationException: Cannot consume scoped service 'XXXX.Entities.MyDbContext' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService'.
```

Here's the Program.cs:

```cs
public static class Program
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      CreateHostBuilder(args).ConfigureLogging(config => config.ClearProviders())
                             .Build()
                             .Run();
   }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((builderContext, services) =>
                services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
                            options.UseSqlServer(builderContext.Configuration
                                                               .GetConnectionString(nameof(MyDbContext)))
                        ).AddHostedService<SenderService>())
            .UseWindowsService();
}
```

SenderService.cs:

```cs
public class SenderService : BackgroundService
{
    public SenderService(IConfiguration configuration, MyDbContext context)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
    }
}
```

and MyDbContext:

```cs
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
    public DbSet<XXXX> XXXX { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end, I figured it out!

### Problem description

What I'm basically doing is using `ConfigureServices` to `AddScoped` object, which is what happens when `AddDbContext<MyDbContext>` is called with only the delegate action filling out the `DbContextOptionsBuilder` that is then passed to my `MyDbcontext` constructor.

The dog is buried in adding the context as `scoped` object, while Service needs it as `singleton` to accept it in its constructor.

### How to remedy that

Well, I can update the piece of code inside the delegate in `ConfigureServices` to treat the DbContext as a singleton:

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
Host
.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.ConfigureServices((builderContext, services) =>
{   
    //this adds the dbContext, needs action that accepts DbContextOptionsBuilder
    services
    .AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(
    optionsAction: (optionsBuilder) => 
        {
            //prepare connection string from IConfiguration existing in HostBuilderContext
            //that was passed to ConfigureServices
            var connectionString = builderContext.Configuration
                                                 .GetConnectionString(nameof(MyDbContext));
            //and tell the optionsBuilder to use the SqlServer with the connectionstring
            //which is then passed as parameter to MyDbContext constructor
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        },
        //!!!IMPORTANT!!! - also specify the lifetime of the context, default is Scoped
        contextLifetime: ServiceLifetime.Singleton,
        optionsLifetime: ServiceLifetime.Singleton)
    
    .AddHostedService<SenderService>()
})
.UseWindowsService();
```

Or, better, **DON'T PASS CONTEXT AS SINGLETON TO THE SERVICE, CREATE IT WHEN NEEDED!**

Which I can do for example by passing just the optionsBuilder like this:

```cs
// ---------in Program.cs------------

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices((builderContext, services) =>
            services.AddSingleton((_) => {
                            //again, get connection string from configuration
                            var connectionString = builderContext.Configuration
                                                                 .GetConnectionString(nameof(MyDbContext));
                            //and return DbContextOptions to be saved as singleton
                            //to be passed to my service as constructor parameter
                            return new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>().UseSqlServer(connectionString).Options;
                        })
                    .AddHostedService<SenderService>())
        .UseWindowsService();

// ---------in SenderService.cs------------
public class SenderService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly DbContextOptions<MyDbcontext> contextOptions;
    public SenderService(IConfiguration configuration, DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> dbContextOptions)
    {
         contextOptions = dbContextOptions;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        ....
        using(var context = new MyDbContext(contextOptions))
        {
           ....
        }
        ....
    }
}
```